# How to change color of underline of Japanese and Chinese composition input text

Tags: css

My team is developing a web application which allow users to enter text to filter data. The filter is invoked after users enter a character in a textbox.

We've found an issue that the filter is not invoked when Chinese users enter Chinese text by a keyboard layout "Microsoft Pinyin New Experience Input Style".

[image]

The root cause is the composition text is not confirm yet.
Normally, browser will show **black underline** to let users know current state of their input.

[image]

However, my **textbox is black** and the users can't see the underline. So they thought the text is already entered.

Could anyone tell me how to change color of this underline, please?

Comment: Interesting, replicating this would be hard because it's a localization issue. I would inspect the element and see what styles are placed on the text while it's being written. See if you can find anything. If you can't, then it's probably not possible.

Comment: In order to replicate this, you just add a keyboard layout Chinese (Simplified, PRC) - Microsoft Pinyin New Experience Input Style. Then open google.com, go to textbox, change your keyboard layout to China - Microsoft Pinyin New Experience Input Style. Then try to enter "beijing".

Comment: I'm personally not using Windows, so I still won't be able to replicate it.

Answer (score 0):

Hi~ I'm not sure this is **right** way.

It would need some more css adjustments to prettified it.

However, hope it could help... it's very simple code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <style>
        .invert {
            -webkit-filter: invert(100%);
            filter: invert(100%);
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" class="invert">
</body>
</html>
```